# DXL script in DOORs

Tags: ibm-doors

How to get collaboration link by dxl script in DOORs IBM?

Which the function or method that I can use?

I want to get all collaboration link for each row in DOORs. I try to with Link and LinkRef but I don't know exactly the formular/syntax for this function.

Answer (score 0):

collaboration links are treated as `ExternalLink`s in DXL.
Check the DXL reference manual at https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/SSYQBZ_9.7.0/com.ibm.doors.requirements.doc/topics/dxl_reference_manual.pdf, chapter 20 "Link", subchapters "External Links" and "OSLC Link Discovery" for details how to handle them

Comment: Hello Mike, 
Do you know convert from OSLC link to web link with DXL?

When I invoked body(extLink), return value is a string (OSLC link). But I need to the corresponding web link.

Comment: I don't have a working environment with OSLC links at hand. Please post the "OSLC link" you get and what you expect to come out of your script. Perhaps there is a term in DXL for such a conversion or one can do a conversion using regular expressions.